# Boost results in Elasticsearch based on string value of doc field

Tags: function, search, boost, elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch mapping that contains a field for language codes, e.g. EN, DE, ES, FR, etc. I'd like to boost all English docs in search results if a user starts a search in English; the same for French, Spanish, German, etc.

I guess, `script_score` is the way to go:

```
"script_score" : {
    "script" : "_score * doc['my_numeric_field'].value"
}
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-script-score

However, I'd need to compare the language code of each indexed document. Having `LANG`as the current language code of the user, this might look like this:

```
"script_score" : {
    "script" : "_score * ("+LANG+" == doc['lang'].value ? 2 : 1)"
}
```

The essence here would be a ternary operator like, in order to boost the document in question with a factor of two in case its language matches the current user's language:

```
LANG == doc['lang'] ? 2 : 1
```

So far, any such function is simply ignored by ES.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `function_score` and more specifically `script_score` is indeed the way to go. The way I would do it is by using a parameter called `LANG` which you would initialize with the language of the current user (e.g. `"LANG": "EN"` below). Then your script just needs to compare the `lang` field of the document with the `LANG` parameter and multiply the score by 2 instead of 1.

```
     {
      "script_score": {
        "script": "_score * (doc.lang.value == LANG ? 2 : 1)",
        "params": {
          "LANG": "EN"
        }
      }
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks. I had to enable scripting in the ES config file first: `script.groovy.sandbox.enabled: on`